# Pytesseract - Not Detecting simple black text on white background

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am cropping sections from a larger image to be scanned by OCR.  The first of two cropped sections is detected ok.  Here is a saved jpeg of the first section:

[image: ID]

I have this other cropped section which pytesseract is absolutely clueless about:
[image]

I use the same code to scan the images:

```
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import image
import pytesseract


def get_crop_as_text(page, left, upper, right, lower, debug_out_nm = ''):
    img = page.crop((left, upper, right, lower))
    # img.save('test_crop' + debug_out_nm + '.jpg', 'JPEG')
    txt = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
    txt = txt.replace('\n','')
    return txt


im = Image.open(dat_file)
id = get_crop_as_text(im, 785, 486, 1492, 589, '_id_')
rrg = get_crop_as_text(im, 1372, 3791, 1482, 3853, '_rrg_')
```

'id' returns '1001' as expected.  The second returns ''.

I have locally saved the crops and then done the scanning of each individual saved file.  In that case, the '-2.0' is detected sometimes.  Literally from the same file, same method, etc.  It is just hit or miss and I can't figure why.

Comment: Output of tesseract is not proper. Sometimes it gives correct result and sometimes no. It's better to use other OCR tools. It's necessary to use tesseract?

Comment: @BarzanHayati - I'm not tied to using tesseract.  Do you have a recommendation for a free/low cost OCR solution that's more reliable?

Comment: If you have enough data, it's better to use YOLO object detection. It has excellent results even in presence of noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes on what finally worked:

1. Switched to easyocr.
2. The latest version of OpenCV gave issues with easyocr.  had to downgrade to version OpenCV ver 4.5.4.60.
3. Converting the image to a Numpy array did not help detecting the minus sign.  Instead, had to save to a temp file and then run the ocr on the file

Sorry about the spacing.  SO gave some weird reaction when I hit its "code" button.

```
def get_crop_as_text(page, left, upper, right, lower, debug_out_nm = ''):

    CROP_FILE = 'crop.jpg'

    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False)

    txt = ''

    try:

        img = page.crop((left, upper, right, lower))

        width, height = img.size

        # img = img.resize((width*10, height*10))

        img.save(CROP_FILE,'JPEG')

        result = reader.readtext(CROP_FILE)

        txt = result[0][1]

        txt = txt.replace('\n','')

    except Exception as e:

        print(e)


    return txt
```

Comment: this model has been trained on which dataset? Does it have proper results for noisy images, too?

Comment: all very good questions.  I'm unsure what easyocr is trained on.  doubtful that it would give reliable results without pre-processing.

Answer (score 1):

You’re facing this issue because you’re using the default page segmentation setting.

I was facing a similar problem where tesseract was detecting the text correctly when part of a larger page but failing in crops and it was failing randomly.

Coming back to the issue at hand, by default tesseract assumes that you’re giving it a full page and that’s why it works perfectly during initial stages of your code.

But once you move towards crops, your text is basically in a single line and this is where tesseract fails.

To do this you have to set page segmentation value to 7, which tells tesseract that you’re expecting the text to be a single line of text. You can get the full list of page segmentation modes for tesseract in [this article.](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/11/15/tesseract-page-segmentation-modes-psms-explained-how-to-improve-your-ocr-accuracy/)

Anyway, for your current code all you need to do is to replace:

```
txt = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

With:

```
txt = str(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=r’--psm 7’))
```

PS:

EasyOCR is not a bad choice either but since I work on CPU, as opposed to GPU it is drastically slow in my case. So that might be something you want to look out for.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try this for my next OCR project.